# Can I compell MSBuild.exe to finish in VBS (64-bit Windows 7)?

Tags: vbscript, msbuild, windows-7-x64

ong story with code samples:
I'm doing automated test builds using vb scripting and I see the following line execute differently in 32-bit and 64-bit Windows 7:

```
CmdLine ("cmd /c C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe C:\Users\tester_kafka\Documents\VisualStudio2012\Projects\CFX_Manager_UITest\CFX_Manager_UITest.sln")
```

where CmdLine is a function like this:

```
Function CmdLine(strCommand) 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set WshShellExec = WshShell.Exec(strCommand) 
Do While WshShellExec.Status = 0
WScript.Sleep 100 
Loop 
End Function
```

In the 32-bit Windows 7 system, the build completes and the vb script proceeds to completion.  In the 64-bit Windows 7 system, the cmd window remains open until closed manually, then the script proceeds to completion.  The goal is, of course, to automate the script in 64-bit to proceed automatically.

I have tried adding the & exit to the line, and the /nr:false switch to MSBuild.exe and messing with the quotes (not sure what else to try, frankly...).  Should I be doing something simpler?  And why should the OS make that much difference?

Any information would be welcome, even if it's not a solution.  Thank you all.

Comment: I did an end run around the Wshell.Status = 0, by adding a timer than lasts a lot longer than the needed build time, so it's working and I only need to know why the Status is not 0 in 64-bit Windows 7 and NOT in 32-bit Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
Function CmdLine(strCommand) 
Set WshShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
WshShell.Run strCommand, , true
End Function
```

Comment: The MSBuild.exe line does not play well with the WshShell.Run, I'm afraid; probably I have too many unusual arguments.  This is why I'm not using it in the first place, sadly.